# implementation for Tor directory server?

Tags: directory, source-code

Is the code of the Tor directory servers open sourced?

If i would like to run my own for the purpose of experimenting, what is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be a directory server, it is merely a configuration change in your TORRC. Anyone can be or advertise that you are a directory server but none of the clients would trust it. The source code for Tor is available here: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/

Comment: thank you! got it. 

I don't intend to present a node of mine as a directory server to the real tor network, i intend to run a mini-Tor network for testing purposes on some nodes that i own, and make them use my directory server.